# Drupal Video module add fields to each video

Tags: drupal, video, drupal-modules, drupal-fields

How can we add fields to each video in the Video module?
I need to add a title and description to each video.
I see there is a Description field for the thumbnail, maybe I can add a title to that?
It looks like It may need to be added to video_helper.inc?

Answer (score 0):

Video module is heavily depends on the Filefield module, so if you need to add title and description to a video when its multiple upload to a single node, then you have to edit the uploadfield module which is extending from Filefield module.

If you want only a title and description for a single video node, you can use CCK field.